# Windows 8 search for folders?

Tags: windows-8, search

How is one supposed to search for folders using Windows 8? It seems like Microsoft neglected to add this functionality to the Modern UI... This is a feature that I often use, and was wondering if there is still a way to do such a thing.

Edit: Searching for files does not return folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To search for **Folders** as apposed to **Files**, open up My Computer and search using the box in the upper right hand corner.
[image]

Comment: This does not work as I described. That search only returns files of the name, not folders.

Comment: @Aierou My bad. Fixed.

Comment: That just worked for me.

Comment: For me, it doesn't search from "My Computer," I have to go into a specific drive.

Comment: @bdukes Odd. I was in the Computer section, were you?

Comment: Alright. This works, but why would Microsoft remove folders from the start search? It worked extremely well in 7.

Comment: @Aierou Because developers. All jokes aside though probably because it confuses most people. They don't want to see or understand file systems, they just want their files. I see this all the time with things like saving files in Temp folders and wondering why it causes odd behavior, or saving things randomly throughout the user profile. I'm all for hiding the underlying file system, it makes my job _much_ easier.

Comment: @r.tanner.f yeah, in the Computer section; it just never started the search